# Trying to rescale the plot to show small concentration differences

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-xarray

In the attached image, only one small dot is seen, representing the point source, but I want to be able to see the entire concentration spread across the map.

[image]

```py
cmap = "jet"
fig = plt.figure()
proj = ccrs.PlateCarree()
ax = plt.axes(projection=proj)
cs = ax.contourf(
    lon,
    lat,
    depo,
    transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(),
    cmap=cmap,
    vmin=depo.min(),
    vmax=depo.max(),
    extend="max",
)
cbar = fig.colorbar(cs, shrink=0.8)

ax.coastlines()
ax.set_title("Conc (ng/m2) 2020-01-28 18.00")
ax.set_xticks([-40, 0, 40])
ax.set_xlabel("longitude [degE]", visible="true")
ax.set_yticks([10, 40, 70])
ax.set_ylabel("latitude [degN]", visible="true")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question is missing some detail and would benefit from being a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are scaling the color map with `vmax` to the largest occuring value in your dataset. Try something like `vmax=0.1 * depo.max()`. Sometimes, the mean value is also useful, e.g. `vmax=1.5 * depo.mean()`  but that depends on the distribution of the values. Also the colors can be easiest specified with the `levels` parameter:

Here is a small example that you can use as starting point

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()

x = np.linspace(-2, 2, 51) + 1
y = np.linspace(-2, 2, 51) - 0.5
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y)
zz = 1 / (xx ** 2 + yy ** 2)
norm=mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=-0.5, vmax=1))
cs = plt.contourf(xx, yy, zz, cmap='RdBu', levels=np.linspace(-0.5, 1, 10), extend='both')
cbar = plt.colorbar(cs, shrink=0.8)
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip. It still does not work though... I tried it and the cbar still shows the very large values and the plot looks strange. I tried playing around with cbarticks as well and with the 90%tile, 10%tile... but nothing works!

Comment: You might have used the wrong vmin/vmax values. For debugging, plotting a histogram of the values can be useful, e.g., `plt.hist(my_array.flatten())`. Then you get an idea how to set the vmin and vmax value correctly.

Comment: How about setting up a non linear colomap of some kind? Could that work? I testing different vmax/vmin values as well. Just that the spread is very large.                   Mean conc:      0.9903941
Standard deviation: 71.22356
Minimum conc: -0.00491313
Maximum conc: 54720.062
0.1th percentile:    0.0
Median:             0.00014076152
99.9th percentile:    111.25607153320777

Comment: Sure, if your data is strongly non-uniformly distributed over a large range then, e.g., using a logarithmic colormap (e.g., `matplotlib.colors.LogNorm()`) could help. But in a way, that's a different question then ;)

Comment: If you allow me one unrelated comment: if there isn't a good reason, don't use "jet" (or the rain bow color map) as it can strongly "distort" the visual perception of the data (see e.g. https://www.kennethmoreland.com/color-advice/BadColorMaps.pdf). Matplotlib comes with a bunch of very good color maps.

Comment: One of the parameters for `contourf` is `levels`: there you can specify the colors values that will exactly show also in the color bar, see my code above. In levels you can now easily change the min/max values. I have also added example data that might be more relevant for your problem. `extend='both'` fixes the problem that no colors outside the levels-range are shown.